# Pandas: Memory difference when saving to csv (Dataframe vs multi-index Series)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv, multi-index

Pandas `to_csv` writes files with very different sizes depending on whether they are multi-index series, or simple unstacked data frames (the latter seem less than half the size).

There is probably some intuition behind this from the csv format, but I can't quite figure it out.

**Why are pandas Series so much larger on .csv format that Dataframes?**

Code to generate an example of this:

```
# imports 
import pandas as pd 
from numpy.random import random 
from random import randint 

# generate some data (1000 x 1000)
n_rows = 1000
n_cols = 1000
large = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((n_rows, n_cols)))

# generate some indexes
large['index_1'] = [randint(0,100) for i in range(n_rows)]
large['index_2'] = [random() for i in range(n_rows)]

# make it a multi-index 
large = large.set_index(['index_1', 'index_2']).sort_index()

# save as stacked and unstacked
large.to_csv('unstacked_example.csv')
large.stack().reset_index().to_csv('stacked_example.csv')
```

Then get the size with `ls -lh`:
unstacked_example.csv - 19M 
stacked_example.csv - 50M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where in the `unstacked` example, you only printed out each index and each column once.  In the `stacked` example, you printed out each index 1000 times and each columns value 1000 times.

***unstacked***

```
large.size + large.index.size + large.columns.size

1002000
```

***stacked***

```
slarge = large.stack()
slarge.size + slarge.index.size

2000000
```

This is why we invented tables... because it is often more convenient and efficient.